# Subclipse and Android question

Tags: android, subclipse

I'm attempting to utilize some code found here:

http://androidtabs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

This includes the bases classes for the demo found here:

http://www.gregbugaj.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/tabwidgetdemo.zip

Anyway, I'd like to keep the two projects separate, referencing the base project whenever I need it in a new project.  Anyway, I installed Subclipse and successfully checked-out the base project. However, in Eclipse, it still throws compiler errors, for instance, "Failed to load properties file for project 'TabWidget'" (a base class).  I edited the Builder settings for this base project yet I still receive the same errors.  Any suggestions?

Also, I realize I could simply copy the missing classes from my base to my demo, but prefer to keep them separate if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need to actually run the base project as an application, you could make it an **Eclipse Library** project.

Right click on project root --> Properties --> Android --> Check "Is Library"

Then in your demo, you tell eclipse to use that project.

Right click on project root --> Properties --> Android --> Library/Add...  Click on the base.

Do a Project --> Clean after this to rebuild the project & hopefully the problems would disappear.